# problem with react after deploying to nginx server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, webserver, nodejs-server

I installed react app on nginx server and build it (it's ok, i followed the instructions),
but i have this problem=>

https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/static/css/main.6094b2de.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/static/js/main.524d9c99.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
etc...

I guess the problem is that the request is sent to https ,because if a follow this link in browser
< https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/static/css/main.6094b2de.css > and change https to http i get some data

`

```
server {
  listen 80;


  location / {
        root /var/www/myWebsite/client/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

   location /api {
        proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8800;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }

}
```

`

any ideas?

---

Answer (score -1):

for HTTPS you need to add an SSL certificate using let's encrypt
please check this [blog](https://www.learnwithjason.dev/blog/deploy-nodejs-ssl-digitalocean#get-a-free-ssl-certificate-with-lets-encrypt)